# Why was vim deleted after system (ubuntu 14.04) update?

Tags: ubuntu, vim

Everytime I compile vim and install it (I always use manual from the [site](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source)), it is deleted after an Ubuntu update (not all updates but some of them).

After such updates ubuntu always ask me to use "apt-get install -f". It seems that the problem is with vim distributions which is located in default repo.

I've googled a lot but didn't find anything about the theme. Can you help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-compiled binaries should be placed in `/usr/local/bin`; the instructions change that default via `--prefix=/usr` and the `VIMRUNTIMEDIR`. With that, you'll get a conflict with the distribution-provided Vim packages, and I guess that's what's causing your problems.

Therefore, drop those special instructions and let Vim install to `/usr/local/...`; you may only have to include `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH` to invoke it.

Comment: Should I just remove ---prefix=/usr and VIMRUNTIMERDIR options? Right?

Comment: Yes; it's basically only `./configure --with-features=HUGE --enable-...; make; sudo make install`